# Find a specific word within a specific folder on a cloud drive?

Tags: finder, search, icloud

I send out monthly wine cases to my clients, and we never send the same wine twice (until the vintage changes).

I need to be able to search through all the existing tasting sheet docs to make sure that I haven't sent, for example, Chateau Haut Brion (if only!) previously.

In pc, I could just go straight to the folder, in this case Wine Club Tasting Sheets, and search that folder and instantly I would find that I did send the specific wine in August 2019 (as an example). I cannot for the life of me see how I do this within Finder/Spotlight or 3rd party app Easy Find.

Comment: is the word you're searching for in the filename or inside file?

Comment: Hi. The word would be within the word document (or several of them). Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, current Microsoft Word versions store documents in a format that Spotlight (apparently) doesn’t know how to scan.

Answer (score 1):

In the Finder Preferences you can chose to search on your Mac or within the current folder (Finder Preferences > Advanced > When Performing a Search: drop down)
Spotlight searches filenames and file contents.

Comment: thanks, I don't get spotlight option - I would attach a screenshot but unsure how to add to this comment

Comment: Sorry, I might have used the wrong term. In the finder window there should be a search box on the top right. Use that to find what you need in the folder. Spotlight is the search tool that searches across your Mac and internet for all kinds of things meeting your search criteria.

Comment: no worries. yes I have seen and used that search bar but it doesn't seem to actually perform a search for a word just a filename. so I am viewing my online drive in Finder. Scroll down to the folder Wineclub Tasting Notes and select it. then search for a word i.e. magpie (which I know is in several of the word docs) but nothing is found.

Comment: when you say you "select" the folder, are you actually opening the folder (double click on it)? The search should apply to all files including filenames in that folder.

Comment: yes the folder is open so I can see the hundred plus word docs